# Is Object-Oriented Programming in Interpreted languages (i.e, PHP) efficient?

Tags: php, performance, oop, interpreted-language

I was just wondering whether it would be worth sticking to non-OOP code for the sake of speed. Also, In commercial web-applications, is OOP generally used or avoided? Which is the standard?

Many Thanks,

Ed

Comment: I soo want to know the answer to this.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to avoid learning oop?

Comment: Not really. I actually find the idea of being able to create re-usable code quite refreshing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard is to favor readable code over efficiency, because most of the time "more efficient code" runs faster by a single millisecond. Object-oriented programming is generally more readable than a non-object-oriented counterpart.

See also this question: [Why are so many web languages interpreted rather than compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340298/why-are-so-many-web-languages-interpreted-rather-than-compiled?rq=1). The majority of a page's load time is spent sending and receiving data or doing database things.

Comment: So would it not make a significant difference to the user?

Comment: @Edward In most cases, no. You shouldn't concern yourself about efficiency unless your code is actually running slow — and remember, [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 4):

OOP is generally used in commercial webapps, and is turning to be the standard. The reason for it is not efficiency - it's code re-usability, code readability, easy documentation, structure, and more importantly modularity!

Answer (score 3):

Object-Oriented code is the standard, but not for performance reasons.  It is really about maintainability.

Code speed is seldom of any real consequence in web applications.  I/O is much more relevant, and most of the optimization people engage in is ultimately designed to reduce I/O:

- Persistent database connections
- Data fragment caching
- Page caching
- Client-side cache headers

Any significant CPU-intensive tasks are usually handled by compiled plug-ins, and made accessible to the interpreted language.  Some common examples:

- PDF Generation
- Image manipulation (Imagik, GD)
- Cryptography (OpenSSL)

Answer (score 1):

I think the OOP overhead is generally negligible for speed performance, and the code will gain much quality.

Commercial applications usually use OOP, if started after that was available (and stable!)